# Ordenar array de array em PHP

Tags: php

```
array (0 => array 1 => int 5 1 => array 2 => int 3 2 => array 8 => int 5);
```

de modo que ele fique assim

```
array (0 => array 1 => int 5 2 => array 8 => int 5 1 => array 2 => int 3 );
```

quero ordenar esse array da seguinte forma pelo valores inteiros dos valor dos sub arrays do maior para o menor tipo no primeiro tem esse valor 5, 3, 5
e quero que fique assim 5,5,3 não importa a ordem das chaves dos arrays inter nem externo mais desses falor que eu coloquei outro exemplo se no lugar de 5,3,5 fosse 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,11,11 ficaria assim com a ordenação 11,11,10,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1

Comment: arsort ou rsort -> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.arsort.php https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rsort.php, seria isso que precisa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Algoritmo de Ordenação

O algoritmo de ordenação que será aplicado nesta resposta é o denominado **Ordenação por Inserção**, ou do inglês, *Insertion Sort*, como é mais conhecido.

A maneira que tal algoritmo funciona assemelha-se à uma pessoa organizando sua mão em um jogo de cartas. Imagine que neste jogo você possui 5 cartas em sua mão, ordenadas numericamente. Desconsiderando as diferentes naipes e focando apenas nos números, vamos supor que sua mão é composta de `[9, 7, 6, 3, 1]`. Ao receber uma nova carta na rodada, você irá posicioná-la em sua mão de forma que a ordenação se mantenha. Por exemplo, você recebeu a carta `4`. Tal carta será posicionada entre as cartas `6` e `3`, de forma que sua mão continue ordenada do maior para o menor: `[9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1]`.

Em termos mais genéricos, a ordenação por inserção funciona percorrendo a lista de valores para cada novo item e, quando determinada condição for satisfeita, insira o novo elemento.

No jogo de cartas, a condição seria `é maior que ..?`. Dado o novo elemento `4`, percorre a lista `[9, 7, 6, 3, 1]` até que `4` seja maior que um elemento. Do início da lista:

- `4 > 9?`, não, continue;
- `4 > 7?`, não, continue;
- `4 > 6?`, não, continue;
- `4 > 3?`, sim, então insira o novo elemento (4) aqui;

Obtendo a lista final `[9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 1]`.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Figura 1**: Figura ilustrativa de como funciona a ordenação por inserção. Fonte: [w3resource](http://www.w3resource.com/php-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-3.php)

---

## Código PHP

Primeiro, vamos supor que a nossa lista de elementos seja definida como:

```
$result = [];
```

Como desejamos ordenar uma lista completa, iremos seguir a ideia apresentada no algoritmo, inserindo na lista um item por vez, pois isso nos garantirá que o item será posicionado no local correto e teremos a lista ordenada no sinal. Os nossos elementos são retirados da lista `$arr`:

```
$arr = [
    0 => [1 => 5], 
    1 => [2 => 3], 
    2 => [8 => 5]
];
```

No PHP, para percorrermos todos os itens de uma lista, podemos utilizar a diretiva `foreach` e, para cada item, o inserimos na lista.

```
$result = [];

foreach ($arr as $item)
{
    $result = insert_sort($result, $item);
}
```

A função `insert_sort` definiremos em breve. O que estamos fazendo neste trecho é: para cada `$item` de `$arr`, insira na lista `$result` e atualize o valor de `$result` contendo o novo item.

**insert_sort(array $result, mixed $item)**

A função `insert_sort` recebe dois parâmetros: a lista onde desejamos inserir o item e o item a ser inserido. A lógica da função é exatamente a explicada no algoritmo, no início da resposta:

```
function insert_sort($result, $item)
{
    // Variável de controle da posição na lista:
    $index = 0;

    // Percorre a lista:
    foreach ($result as $j => $value)
    {
        // Verifica a condição: (novo item) > (item da lista)?
        if (array_values($item)[0] > array_values($value)[0])
        {
            // Sim, então pare de percorrer a lista
            break;
        }

        // Não, então continue para a próxima posição:
        $index++;
    }

    // O novo item será inserido na posição $index
    // Para isso, precisamos abrir o espaço na lista com a função array_splice:
    array_splice($result, $index, 0, array($item));

    // Retorne a lista ordenada:
    return $result;
}
```

Tal como comentado: percorre toda a lista até que a condição seja verdadeira. Insere o novo valor e retorne a lista ordenada. Desta forma, no final, a lista `$result` será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [8] => 5
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )
)
```

> Você pode ver o código funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fcqy/0).

---

**Nota**: A condição utilizada para a ordenação varia conforme a necessidade. Neste caso, nossos itens da lista são do tipo `array` e queremos ordenar de forma decrescente conforme o valor na primeira posição. Com a função `array_values`, retornamos a lista de todos os valores do `array` e, ao acessar o índice `[0]`, retornamos apenas o primeiro, ordenando, desta forma, em relação aos valores `5, 3, 5`, como dado no enunciado.

---

## Versão otimizada

O mesmo resultado pode ser obtido da seguinte forma:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
  return current($b) - current($a);
});
```

Neste caso, a própria lista `$arr` estará ordenada. A lógica executada é exatamente a mesma, só que escrita com menos linhas, devido ao uso da função `usort` e `current`.

> Você pode ver o código funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fctd/0).

---

Documentação: [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-splice.php), [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php), [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php), [`current`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.current.php)

Comment: Cara deu certo tem como você da uma explicada melhor poxa cara raciocínio de gênio me bati muito para obter esse resulta que vc consegui com poucas linhas!

Comment: Alguma parte em especial que ficou dificil de entender? Bom, melhorarei a explicação como um todo. Ela está bem fraca mesmo.

Comment: @Joao, desculpe-me a demora, mas editei a resposta com uma explicação mais completa. Veja se compreende agora.

Comment: Cara bacana esse raciocínio agora ficou claro muito obrigado!

Comment: Se possível, marque a resposta como válida para indicar que o problema já foi resolvido.

Comment: ok como faço isso sou novo no forum?

Comment: No lado esquerdo da resposta, possui o sistema de votos. Logo abaixo da seta para baixo, há o botão com formato de um "certo", basta clicar nele.

Comment: Anderson outra dúvida como faço para acessar as chaves dos sub array que estão como valor! exemplo quero acessa os valores das chaves no exemplo acima 1, 8, 2

Comment: [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: Consegui assim se tiver uma ideia melhor comenta ai!   for($i=0; $i <count($result); $i++){
                                                foreach($result[$i] as $position => $value){
                                                       var_dump($position);  
                                                }
                                            }

Comment: @Joao, https://repl.it/Fe1w/0

Answer (score 0):

Abrindo mão de performance, já que teus índices internos parecem não seguir nenhum padrão também, fiz uma solução pra ti:

```
echo "<pre>";
$arr = array(0 => array(1 => 5), 1 => array(2 => 3), 2 => array(8 => 5));

$arr = array_values($arr);

$tmp = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $val = array_values($value);
    array_push($tmp, $val[0]);
}

rsort($tmp);

foreach($tmp as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = array($value);
}

print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Mas assim o índice da `array` interna é perdido, certo? No resultado final, todos os índices das `array` internas são zeros.

Comment: Como ele pouco fala dos índices eu não os armazenei, mas seria possível caso seja necessário.

Answer (score -6):

É só usar um [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php) com a variável que está o grupo de arrays que você quer inverter...

```
$exemplo = array_reverse($var);
```

Agora se você quer re-organizar todas as arrays em ordem crescente ou decrescente, você pode usar o arsort (do maior ao menor) ou o asort (do menor ao maior).

```
$exemplo = arsort($var);
```

[Documentação sobre array sorting](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php)

Comment: Não custava nada ter pesquisado um pouco no site do php...